# Why can't I use blob.text() in my React Native Expo app?

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, blob

I am trying to use the [blob.text()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob/text) function in my React Native Expo app ([example Expo snack demonstrating the issue here](https://snack.expo.dev/z_ZmeCjAT)). When I call this function on a blob, I get the following error: `Unhandled promise rejection Error: "testBlob.text is not a function. (In 'testBlob.text()', 'testBlob.text' is undefined)" in _callee$ << tryCatch <<  << asyncGeneratorStep`

Creating a blob in this way then calling the text() function works just fine when running the code in the Chrome dev console- not sure why this is only happening in my Expo app.

Any clue why this is and/or what I need to do to be able to use the text() function on a blob?

Tried: Creating a new Blob object from a string with the linked blob constructor then calling the text() function to get the string back.
Expected behavior: Calling blob.text() should return the string that the blob was created from.
What actually resulted: The text() function is not recognized.